# VB.NET How To Continuously Read TCP Stream

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcplistener

Morning,

After much mucking around I have finally got my little TCP Listener application to connect to my server and listen to the traffic.

I am able to connect and get the initial response from the port however it does not return the stream traffic constantly, I need to constantly monitor the ports traffic so I can effectively post it to a database, can anyone help me with how I would loop this?

Here is my code at the moment:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices '   DllImport
Imports System.Security.Principal '  WindowsImpersonationContext
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

Private Delegate Sub AppendTextBoxDelegate(ByVal TB As RichTextBox, ByVal txt As String)

Private Sub AppendTextBoxes(ByVal TB As RichTextBox, ByVal txt As String)
    If TB.InvokeRequired Then
        TB.Invoke(New AppendTextBoxDelegate(AddressOf AppendTextBoxes), New Object() {TB, txt})
    Else
        TB.Text = ""
        TB.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + txt
    End If
End Sub

Dim clientSocket As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
Dim serverStream As NetworkStream

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AppendTextBoxes(RichTextBox1, "Client Started")
End Sub

Private Sub My_BgWorker_DoWork1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Try
        clientSocket.Connect("192.168.1.22", 21055)
        AppendTextBoxes(RichTextBox1, "Client Socket Program - Server Connected ...")

        Dim serverStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()

        If serverStream.CanRead Then
            Do While clientSocket.Connected
                Dim outStream As Byte() = _
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Message from Client$")
                serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
                serverStream.Flush()

                Dim inStream(10024) As Byte
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
                Dim returndata As String = _
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)
                AppendTextBoxes(RichTextBox1, "Data from Server : " + returndata)
                Console.WriteLine("Data from Server : " + returndata)
            Loop
        Else
            AppendTextBoxes(RichTextBox1, "No Data to Receive")
            clientSocket.Close()
            serverStream.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(Environment.NewLine & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & ex.StackTrace, "Dumping To Log", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged

    'AppendTextBoxes(RichTextBox1.Text, "DONE!")
    'ProgBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled Then
        MsgBox("Cancelled")
    End If

    Console.WriteLine("Finished Processing - Background Worker 1")
    AppendTextBoxes(RichTextBox1, "Finished Getting Stream!")

End Sub
End Class
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, this is for a project I need to have in by 1st Jan 2015 :(

James

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint in your while?.. You have your condition to run while connected which means thats true the first time. Change that to: Do While Not Client.Connected

Comment: If you do that what then determines when it gets disconnected.?

Comment: Hi Mr CodExer, there is no ClientSocket.Disconnected. I am going to try a timer loop, I can return the first 'connected' message of my TCP stream but can't return all the traffic after it.

Comment: Do Until Not clientSocket.Connected seems to have worked a charm Mr CoDeXeR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your condition to run while connected which means thats true the first time. Change that to:

```
 Do Until Not Client.Connected
```